# Update tableView after dismissal of popover view controller swift storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview, which is a list of football matches. In my navigation I have a "plus" sign where I can add a new match to. This is presented as a popover and it works very fine. Although when I use
`dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` and apply changes to my database.
The tableview does not update and I have to change page in the app, to make it update. '

Any suggesting for making my tableview updating after a popover has been showed? I have tried updating the tableview in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Have you tried adding `self.tableView.reloadData()`, in your TableViewController's `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Yes, this does not work. It does not seems to be called when I dismiss the popover.

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss your popover controller at that time check which is presenting view controller if it is your VC with tableview you want to reload then reload your tableview in viewWillDisappear method of your popoverVC

```
class PopOverViewController {
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let tableVC = presentingViewController as? TableViewController {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableVC.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it does not update the tableView? However, when I override viewWIllDisappear, it does not include super.viewWillDisappear

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to reload data from a core data database**

I don't know what data base you are using but I assume it's Core Data

If it's the case:

1. create un Unwind Segue (control drag the button you're using to dismiss the controller to the exit icon on top right of controller, give it an identifier).
2. add this code to both your tableview controller and popoverController

here is the code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var matches = [Match](){ //Core Data object
        didSet {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation { //reloading after adding a new match (safe)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    //...

    //this unwind function executes after dismissing your popover controller
    @IBAction func unwindToThemeList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        matches = //... retreive your data

        //this code works with var theme {didset} to make sure new matches are added
    }

}
```

and

```
class popoverController: UIViewController {

     //this section of code lets you do operations before dismissing the controller
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

         guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }

         if identifier == TheNameYouGaveToYourIdentifier {
             //Do your saves
         }          
}
```

So when you press the button to dismiss, it will trigger the unwind segue, going through override prepare first then through unwind for segue.

prepare section in pop viewController lets you do your saves

unwind section in tableviewController lets you retrieve your data

then to reload efficiently use the didst section

Comment: @Peter Holdensgaard did that answer helped you?